# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar lo que esta dentro de un patrón con expresiones regulares de R?

Tags: regex, rstudio

```
shoppinc_x <- c( 
            "De nuevo\n(no coincide\n\na)\ntambien hola De nuevo(ahora con esto si)\n\n y va")
```

De este texto en R quiero eliminar desde "De nuevo" hasta el "\n\n", intenté hacerlo pero no encuentro una solución.

```
print(str_replace_all(shoppinc_x, "De nuevo(.|\n)*\n\n", ""))
```

Como salida necesito que salga así:

```
"a)\ntambien hola  y va"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función `str_remove_all()` es una abreviación de `str_replace_all(replacement = "")`. El siguiente código resuelve tu problema.

```r
str_remove_all(string, "De nuevo(\n|.){0,20}\n\n")

# [1] "a)\ntambien hola  y va"
```

La diferencia está en que uso `{0,20}` en lugar del asterisco después de `(\n|.)`. Al usar el asterisco la expresión es "ambiciosa" y usa todos los caracteres que puede, es mejor indicar un mínimo (0) y un máximo (20 en este caso), para lograr lo que buscas.

Aquí tienes el "cheatsheet" de manipulación de strings en R https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/blob/master/strings.pdf